# How do I check for collisions between any two turtles?

Tags: netlogo

Netlogo is honestly very weird for me, but I've been trying to make Space Invaders for a project. I need to be able to check the distance between multiple turtles of the same breed in order to run a collision check. How do I do this?

```
    to shoot
  ask turtle 0 [
    hatch 1
    [
      set shape "dot"
      set size 2
      set color red
      set ctrl "projectile"
      set xcor [xcor] of turtle 0
      set ycor [ycor] of turtle 0 + 2
      
      repeat 40
      [
        ifelse ycor < 15 and distancexy [xcor] of turtle 1 [ycor] of turtle 1 > 0.5
        [
          set ycor ycor + 1
        ]
        [
          ifelse distancexy [xcor] of turtle 1 [ycor] of turtle 1 < 0.5
          [
            ask turtle 1 [die]die][die]
        ]
        wait .01
        
      ]
      
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: I can't understand what your code is trying to do. When you say 'check the distance between multiple turtles' do you mean (1) you want to find the minimum distance to other turtles (2) count how many turtles are within some distance (3) kill any turtles within some distance (4) place the new turtle so that it is at least some distance from all  others (5) something else?

Comment: i want it to check if any of the turtles are within x distance and kill those turtles. Sorry for the confusion @JenB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want something like a 'hero' turtle to shoot all the turtles within some distance. I have modified your code a little but the basic idea is sound. You didn't really have a step for identifying the targets. I also simplified the movement by using `face` and used a `while` because there is no guarantee it will take 40 steps to get to the target.

```
to shoot
  let shooter turtle 0   ; or however the shooter is selected
  ask shooter
  [ let targets other turtles with [distance myself < 0.5       ; finds the targets
    if any? targets
    [ let this-target one-of targets
      face this-target                 ; so shooter is facing the target so trail better
      ; do the shooting
      [ hatch 1
        [ set shape "dot"
          set size 2
          set color red
          set ctrl "projectile"
          let step-distance 0.02
          while distance this-target > step-distance
          [ face this-target            ; you don't need to worry about coordinates
            forward step-distance
            wait .01
          ]
          die                           ; once close enough, projectile dies
        ]
        ask this-target [ die ]         ; and kills the target
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

This code is completely untested and needs another loop to get all the targets. Usually you don't use loops much in NetLogo, but an `ask` would change this into the perspective of the target rather than the shooter.